# One word for parking the car in the workshop for repair

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an appropriate word for parking a car at the Workshop, for repair in the coming days. The word **deposit** gives an impression of a financial transaction.

> I *put/deposited/parked* my car in the workshop for repair.

What can be the most appropriate word in this context?

Comment: *left*........?

Comment: Do you want to emphasize the parking, or the leaving, or anything specific to a car? You can *drop off* something you intend to pick up later like a car at the mechanic, a shirt at the dry cleaner, or a child at daycare. But that would just generally indicate leaving it there, not specifically parking a car in the workshop where it's going to be worked on.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. You can add this as an answer.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Well, left would be too simplistic :)

Comment: Nevertheless, it's what many people would say. Usually you park your car _outside_ the workshop and the mechanic drives it in there when he's ready to start work.

Comment: took/left/drop off/ drove my car to the workshop but not parked really.  There are **tons** of ways to say it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Drop off*** is a phrase that indicates you are purposefully leaving something behind somewhere, possibly with the intent of returning for it later. You can drop off your car at the mechanic, your shirt at the dry cleaner, or your child at daycare. You could also drop off a letter at the post office or a friend at the airport, without any intent of coming back for them.

The phrase does not connote anything specific to cars or mechanics or parking, just the act of bringing something somewhere expressly for the purpose of leaving it there.

Comment: We also use **bring/take in** for servicing and repair work.

Comment: As a Brit, 'drop off' is the one I'd be least likely to use, in favour of 'took' or 'left'. idk whether that's just me or a British preference, but 'drop off' just isn't in my daily vocabulary.